# Apache Spark Query with HiveContext doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I use Spark 1.6.1. In my Spark Java Programm I connect to a Postgres Database and register every table as a temporary table via JDBC. For example:

```
Map<String, String> optionsTable = new HashMap<String, String>();
optionsTable.put("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database?user=postgres&password=passwd");
optionsTable.put("dbtable", "table");
optionsTable.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
DataFrame table = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(optionsTable).load();        
table.registerTempTable("table");
```

This works without problems:

```
hiveContext.sql("select * from table").show();
```

Also this works:

```
DataFrame tmp = hiveContext.sql("select * from table where value=key");
tmp.registerTempTable("table");
```

And then I can see the contents of the table with:

```
hiveContext.sql("select * from table").show();
```

But now I have a Problem. When I execute this:

```
hiveContext.sql("SELECT distinct id, timestamp FROM measure, measure_range w WHERE tble.timestamp >= w.left and tble.timestamp <= w.right").show();
```

Spark does nothing, but at the origin databse on Postgres it works very good. So I decided to modify the query a little bit to this:

```
hiveContext.sql("SELECT id, timestamp FROM measure, measure_range w WHERE tble.timestamp >= w.left").show();
```

This Query is working and gives me results. But the other query is not working. Where is the difference and why is the first query not working, but the second is working good?

And the database is not very Big. For testing it has a size of 4 MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to select a distinct ID, you need to select timestamp as a part of an aggregate function and then group by ID. Otherwise, it doesn't know which time stamp to pair with the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I remove the distinct the Query is working. But I dont know how to solve my problem with your solution as you described. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Well you'll have to decide which corresponding timestamps you're interested in getting with the IDs. For example, if you want the newest, it would be `select id, max(timestamp) from measure, measure_range w WHERE tble.timestamp >= w.left group by ID`

Comment: I forgot the tble in the query. The not working query is: SELECT distinct id, timestamp FROM measure tble, measure_range w WHERE tble.timestamp >= w.left and tble.timestamp <= w.right. When i execute then: SELECT id, max(timestamp) FROM measure tble, measure_range w WHERE tble.timestamp >= w.left and tble.timestamp <= w.right group by wid. Spark also is doing nothing. At the Web UI it says a job is running, but nothing will happen.

Comment: The query is working well now. But Spark itself seems to do nothing, because I used a ODBC to connect to a Postgres DB with a very slow network connection. Exporting the table into local hdfs, so Spark can acces the Data faster, solved the Problem.